# how to use regular expression extractor in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

what is regular expression extractor?

what it actually does?

How to use regular expression extractor in real time applications?

I'm a beginner to jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

[Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) is one of JMeter's [Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), it can be used for extracting "interesting" parts of the response (or whole response) and saving it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) for later re-use.

The most straightforward use case is [handling **correlation**](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter), for example: your application under test uses a [CSRF-token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), it comes as a [HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) with the each response and is expected to come as a request parameter to double-check request origin.

Given above situation you won't be able just to record and replay the test scenario, you will need to extract this header value from each response and add it to the next request and one of the options is using the Regular Expression Extractor.

Comment: thanks for your clarification.but kindly say how to use the regular expression for an application because I feel difficult to use this and I don't know how to use the regular expression extractor for a unique id

Answer (score 0):

I am providing here simpler example whatever the Dmitri added, for Example, this is sample rest API call "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2".
[image: screenshot]